# Read pattern from test file by using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to build a macro which can read data pattern from the text file and update the same on a spreadsheet.

text file

```
Client: shubham chaturvedi 
File Name: CONDARMIT20181030105226.xml 
EDI Reference Number:  
Temp Incident ID: ARMIT1810301012 
Element Name: xyskjd/kjdhsjhk/jhuyiijljf 
Attribute:  
Field Number: 1001 
Validation Error: 901 
Error: ARMIT1810301012 already exists.

Client: anupam chaturvedi 
File Name: CONDARCHR20181030125104.xml 
EDI Reference Number:  
Temp Incident ID: ARCHR1810301007 
Element Name: xyskjd/kjdhsjhk/jhuyiijljf 
Attribute:  
Field Number: 1001 
Validation Error: 901 
Error: ARCHR1810301007 already exists.

Client: anupam chaturvedi 
File Name: CONDARCHR20181108200819.xml 
EDI Reference Number:  
Temp Incident ID: ARCHR1811081013 
Element Name: xyskjd/kjdhsjhk/jhuyiijljf 
Attribute:  
Field Number: 1001 
Validation Error: 901 
Error: ARCHR1811081013 already exists.

Client: Gunjan sharma 
File Name: CONDGunjan sharma20181030152228.xml 
EDI Reference Number:  
Temp Incident ID: Gunjan sharma1810291003 
Element Name: xyskjd/kjdhsjhk/jhuyiijljf 
Attribute:  
Field Number: 1001 
Validation Error: 901 
Error: Gunjan sharma1810291003 already exists.

Client: Vinayak Chaturvedi 
File Name: Retry_Retry_Retry_CONDCHART20181125125646.xml 
EDI Reference Number:  
Temp Incident ID: CHART1811251556 
Element Name: xyskjd/kjdhsjhk/jhuyiijljf 
Attribute:  
Field Number: 1001 
Validation Error: 901 
Error: CHART1811251556 already exists.

Client: Vinayak Chaturvedi 
File Name: CONDCHART20181108125939.xml 
EDI Reference Number:  
Temp Incident ID: CHART1811081252 
Element Name: xyskjd/kjdhsjhk/jhuyiijljf 
Attribute:  
Field Number: 1001 
Validation Error: 901 
Error: CHART1811081252 already exists.

Client: Vinayak Chaturvedi 
File Name: CONDCHART20181108175802.xml 
EDI Reference Number:  
Temp Incident ID: CHART1811081263 
Element Name: xyskjd/kjdhsjhk/jhuyiijljf 
Attribute:  
Field Number: 1001 
Validation Error: 901 
Error: CHART1811081263 already exists.
```

I just want to values after `Temp Incident ID:`, `Error:` and `Element Name:`
to be updated on a spreadsheet.

I am able to get the result by using this code but only for one time. Please help me with the code which can read data of the entire file.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, posElement As Integer, posError As Integer
    myFile = "C:\test\NFR.txt"

    'myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    Open myFile For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        text = text & textline
    Loop
    Close #1

    posElement = InStr(text, "Element")
    posError = InStr(text, "Error")

    Range("A1").Value = Mid(text, posElement + 14, 36)
    Range("B1").Value = Mid(text, posError + 16, 32)

End Sub
```

Comment: I separated the attributes out to have their own lines. If instead each entry is entered into the text file as a single line, feel free to revert my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood your question you can try this code:

after execute the macro you get this one: **EDITED THE IMAGE**
[image]

**EDITED THE CODE:** to answer your comment

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, posElement As Integer, posError As Integer, posTime As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ok As Boolean

    ok = False ' there are two string with "Error" word
    i = 1 ' use the number for write into new row the data...
    myFile = "C:\test\NFR.txt"
    'myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    Open myFile For Input As #1
   Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        'text = text & textline
        text = textline
        'MsgBox text
        posTime = InStr(text, "Temp Incident ID")
        posElement = InStr(text, "Element")
        posError = InStr(text, "Error")

        'control the Temp incident ID word
        If posTime <> 0 Then

           Cells(i, 1) = Mid(text, posTime + 18, 33)
            'i = i + 1
        End If
        'control the Element word
        If posElement <> 0 Then

           Cells(i, 2) = Mid(text, posElement + 14, 36)
           ' i = i + 1
        End If

        'this code control the Error word
        If ok And posError <> 0 Then
           Cells(i, 3) = Mid(text, posError + 7, 32)
           i = i + 1
        End If
        If posError <> 0 Then
           ok = Not (ok)
        End If

    Loop
    Close #1
    'auto Fit column
    Columns("A:C").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Into file txt there are two line with Error word and for this reason i have used boolean variable "ok". I have used "i" variable for to write the text desiderated into rows

Hope this helps

Comment: works!!greatly appreciate the assistance you have provided me. it would be great if i can import the same on separate  column. A,B and C

Comment: I have updated the code for your need...If you want to start the data from row 2 you can write in variable i the value 2(to pass i=1 in i=2).The last row of code i have added autofit the column...

Comment: Works for me ... Thank you.